# neo4j huge graph and solution

Tags: java, neo4j

I have quite a big network in a CSV file. It containt 450k nodes and 45 000 000 relationships. As I've read in neo4j documentation this type of database can handle such a big network.

I've also read that I can use embeded server as well as stand alone one.

My question is what is the difference between them? I would like to have a server which holds its database state.

Second question is that I can use REST API to perform operations on database, an Java API to do that.

What is the difference in performance ? I would like for example to have as an output all nodes levels.

Is it possible to load graph from CSV?

What is the best solution for my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The embedded database sits in the same process as your application, meaning that there's no network overhead (so embedded is much faster). Of course both keep the data, that's why you have a database to begin with :-)

You can even use the embedded mode and standalone server at the same time, see: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/server-embedded.html

For loading lots of data in one go, the BatchInserter should be used, see: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/indexing-batchinsert.html

Answer (score 5):

Here is the code you would use with the Neo4j-Batch-Inserter to import the call-records, instead of generating the data on the fly you would of course read it from a file and split each record accordingly.

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.RelationshipType;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.index.BatchInserterIndex;
import org.neo4j.helpers.collection.MapUtil;
import org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneBatchInserterIndexProvider;
import org.neo4j.kernel.impl.batchinsert.BatchInserterImpl;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

import static org.neo4j.helpers.collection.MapUtil.map;

public class CallRecordImportBatch {

    public static final int MILLION = 1000000;
    public static final int BATCH_SIZE = MILLION;
    public static final int CALLS = 45 * MILLION;
    public static final int USERS = CALLS / 100;
    public static final File STORE_DIR = new File("target/calls_"+ CALLS);
    private static final Random rnd = new Random();

    enum MyRelationshipTypes implements RelationshipType {CALLED}

    private static String randomPhoneNumber() {
        final int phoneNumber = rnd.nextInt(USERS);
        return String.format("%013d", phoneNumber);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        CallRecordImportBatch importBatch = new CallRecordImportBatch();
        importBatch.createGraphDatabase();
        System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + " ms: "+ "Create Database");
    }

    private BatchInserterImpl db;
    private BatchInserterIndex phoneNumberIndex;

    private void createGraphDatabase() throws IOException {
        if (STORE_DIR.exists()) FileUtils.cleanDirectory(STORE_DIR);
        STORE_DIR.mkdirs();
        db = new BatchInserterImpl(STORE_DIR.getAbsolutePath(),
                MapUtil.stringMap("cache_type", "weak",
                        "neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory", "500M",
                        "neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory", "2000M",
                        "neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory", "1000M",
                        "neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory", "0M",
                        "neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory", "0M"
                ));
        final LuceneBatchInserterIndexProvider indexProvider = new LuceneBatchInserterIndexProvider(db);
        phoneNumberIndex = indexProvider.nodeIndex("Caller", MapUtil.stringMap("type", "exact"));
        phoneNumberIndex.setCacheCapacity("Caller", 1000000);

        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Map<String,Long> cache = new HashMap<String,Long>(USERS);
        try {
            for (int call=0;call< CALLS;call++) {
                if (call % BATCH_SIZE == 0) {
                    System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + " ms: "+ String.format("calls %d callers %d", call, cache.size()));
                    time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }
                final String callerNumber = randomPhoneNumber();
                final int duration = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() % 3600);
                final String calleeNumber = randomPhoneNumber();

                long caller = getOrCreateCaller(cache, callerNumber);
                long callee = getOrCreateCaller(cache, calleeNumber);

                db.createRelationship(caller, callee, MyRelationshipTypes.CALLED, map("duration", duration));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + " ms: " + String.format("calls %d callers %d", CALLS, cache.size()));
        indexProvider.shutdown();
        db.shutdown();
    }

    private Long getOrCreateCaller(Map<String, Long> cache, String number) {
        final Long callerId = cache.get(number);
        if (callerId!=null) return callerId;
        long caller = createCaller(number);
        cache.put(number, caller);
        return caller;
    }

    private long createCaller(String number) {
        long caller = db.createNode(map("Number", number));
        phoneNumberIndex.add(caller, map("Number", number));
        phoneNumberIndex.flush();
        return caller;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using this code: few lines which are correct: 1 ms: calls 0 callers 0
10431 ms: calls 1000000 callers 444678
5651 ms: calls 2000000 callers 449949
5376 ms: calls 3000000 callers 449998
5652 ms: calls 4000000 callers 450000 and then: \target\calls_45000000\neostore.propertystore.db] Unable to allocate direct buffer
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: you should probably run the program with enough heap for the intermediate users cache, e.g. -Xmx4G (depending on your user-count)

Answer (score 1):

There is an [java-API](https://github.com/neo4j/java-rest-binding) to perform REST operations.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-rest-graphdb</artifactId>
    <version>1.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
or last milestone
    <version>1.5.M02.U1</version>
</dependency>
```

What do you mean by:

> I would like for example to
>   have as an output all nodes levels.

Regarding your other questions - what does your data model look like?

Comment: my data model is based on Call Detail Records. I simply have got userA, UserB, call duration and so on ... In my graph database I would like to have connection between nodes (user) with the attribute (number of connections) and the user needs to have attribute (active/inactive) as the one may already quit the telecomunication network

Comment: How are the users identified in your file? By phone# ? I assume you later want to look the up by phone# to run queries on the db? The code for be quite straightforward (this is a similar example, I repost another one tomorrow: https://gist.github.com/1375679)